# Android sleep of death (SOD)

Tags: sleep

I purchased a new Android Phone which is pre-installed with V2.1 Eclair. At least once in a day phone gets dead (At this stage I cannot press and any key or unable to make/receive calls). The only option I have at this stage is to remove and re-insert my phone's battery.

I googled all the day for it and found many people says that the issue is with wifi. But I never enabled/used Wifi before. This happens more than once in a day. I took my phone to service centre and they reinstalled OS but still the issue persists. I strongly believe its issue with s/w. Anybody help me get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of phone?

Comment: @Chance - Its MicroMax A60.

Comment: You don't need to remove & re-insert battery.. try pressing & holding power button for 10 seconds & release..

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I tried that before. But no use.

Comment: Have you tried using a different battery?  Low chance this will help, but I'd give that a shot just to rule out the possibility of a defective battery.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously consider rooting and installing a custom ROM.  I've installed custom ROMs which gave me the SOD issue - my point is that I believe SOD is in fact tied to what ROM (whether stock or custom) you are running. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device) details various things on rooting.  For specific directions on rooting and custom ROM for your phone model, you'll have to do a search here for that or on Google.